# Pass JSON Array from PHP to Java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have went through many solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488538/json-php-array-to-javascript) but not getting json in java script getting an error.In my myfile.php file it contains

```
<?php
 ................
print json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysql_close($con);
?>
<html>
    <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="example2.js"></script>
        <script>
           var json= loadJsonFromPHP(<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>);
           //var json= <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

In my example2.js file

```
var loadJsonFromPHP = function(json) {
    console.log(json);
}

function init(){
  // init data
  var json =loadJsonFromPHP(json);
 }
```

getiing an error **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**  at **console.log(json);**,I am new to PHP ,and have no idea where am i getting wrong,

i have tried with .getJson in my js but getting error ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
function init(){
      // init data
var json=$.getJSON('http://localhost/myfile.php', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

}
```

Stuck completely,any help,thanks.

Comment: have you included jquery.js ?

Comment: I have included jquery.min.js file.

Comment: I think you have to drop this function and keep : var json = <?php echo json_encode($data) ?>; access to json as a regular object. ie: var l = json.l, var i = json.i, etc...

Comment: then you need to `$.parseJSON()` in your second example, cause the variable json is string at the moment.

Comment: @VaheShadunts same error ReferenceError: $ is not defined ,thanks

Comment: try to use 'jQuery' instead of '$' maybe the jquery which you have loaded is older version.

Comment: @VaheShadunts jQuery is not defined,after defining that.

Comment: that means that you haven't include jquery, or url is broken.. press ctrl + U in your browser and click on jquery script url, look what happens.

Comment: hey I can see complete jquery.min.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally **XMLHttpRequest** worked out for me in example2.js ,hope it will help.

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest( );
 request.open("GET", "my.php", false);
 request.send(null);
  var json = eval ("(" + request.response + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your myfile.php should only contan echo json_encode($data)

Answer (score 0):

In "myfile.php" you can do something like this...

```
<?php
$array = array(
   "success" => true,
   "message" => "Greetings from the Server!"
);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

In your HTML file...

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script> <!-- your path to jquery goes here -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="target">Message from Server will appear here</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // On ready 
    $(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myfile.php',
        // Before sending the request, show a loading message
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#target").html("Waiting for response...");
        }
    })
    .done(function(response){
        // Write the response message to the target div
        $("#target").html(response.message);
    });
</script>

<body>
</html>
```

And that should really do it.

You can reference the jQuery documentation for `.ajax` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you need to parse the JSON string:

```
var jsonobj = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($data) ?>');
```

Comment: JSON.parse is not part of jQuery. Are you sure your jQuery library is properly included?

Answer (score 0):

In `http://localhost/myfile.php` make sure you have:

```
//You cannot have any echo here you must have clean json-string.
$json = json_encode( $data );
if( json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE ){
    http_response_code(200);//ok
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    die( $json );
}else{
    http_response_code(500);//server error
    die( 'Cannot encode $data.' );
}
```