# Remove values from array onclick without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php

I have a one form and onclick i want to remove image id from array without page refresh and after submit form i will update it in the DB.

I am using following code for this but no any success.

PHP Code:-

```
$total = count($oldimage);
                    //print_r($oldimage);
                    for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
                    {
                        $fimgsql="select * from cc_tbl_img_vid_upload where id='$oldimage[$i]'";
                        $gimgname=mysqli_query($db,$fimgsql) or die('Error');
                        $rw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($gimgname);
                        ?><b id="rm<?=$i?>">Remove<?=$rw['upload_url']?></b><br/><br/>
                            <script>$( "#rm<?=$i?>" ).click(function() {
                                <?php unset($oldimage[$i]);?>
                                alert(<?php echo $oldimage[$i]; ?>);
                                $( "#rm<?=$i?>" ).hide();
                            });</script>
                        <?php
                    }
                        sort($oldimage);
                        $oldimage=implode(',',$oldimage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't directly execute PHP (server-side) based on a JavaScript (client-side) event like you have in your code.

You need to handle your arrays in JavaScript. You can `json_encode` a PHP array and use the JSON array in your JavaScript, which is probably the closest you will get to doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Just tell me How i will use it in my scenario?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488538/json-php-array-to-javascript - Have a look at that

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible the way you want to do it.PHP is serverside - which means you need to send a request to the server and get the response back(refreshing/changing page) while js is client side, and manipulates the UI, in order to achive that you must use AJAX (making a request from behind, and not seen by the user and getting the response, and based on it's output change the UI for the user)

Read this link - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ajax isn't that hard, but you must understand it, if you have php/mysql/html/css/js/jquery knowledge you will get it in no time.